# icon as an image

Tags: vb.net, icons

is it possible to use icon file as a image for a button in visual basic?

f.e.
I have 3 buttons that need to have 3 icons when you click the button the icon of the button needs to be the icon of the form is this posible?

> btnIcon1 = my.resources.ICO1
>
> btnIcon2 = my.resources.ICO2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most basic method to do that:

```
myButton.Image = Me.Icon.ToBitmap
```

You can also use:

```
myButton.Image = My.Resources.myIcon.ToBitmap
```

Both of these methods extract and use the 32x32 icon from the .ico file.

Comment: Any way to grab the 16x16 icon from the .ico?